# How do I store the time and date, that a time driven trigger activates, in a Google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

What im trying to do is store the static values created by importing dynamic data from an url then compare those values, to new sample sets (sampled at 5 minute intervals) of the same dynamic data values. Then compare the 2 sample sets of static values and highlight any changes in the second sample set.

I want to give each sample set its own timestamp, based on the time the installable time driven trigger runs the script. Is this possible?

Comment: This is all very possible. Have you tried any code yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `new Date()` immediately when the script starts.